# An application that read go files and execute it

Tags: go

I am working on my webapplication and using the revel framework. To execute an revel application, I run
the following code

```
revel run myapp
```

Now, I am really wonder how revel approximately works. My question is, how do revel framework execute myapp with many go files, that I wrote for the application? Is revel
a virtual machine?

How can I write an application in Go and read Go files and execute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revel is a pre-processor rather than a framework. It abstracts Go's workings away and introduces it's own [code structure and concepts](http://revel.github.io/manual/organization.html). This is generally frowned upon in the Go community but that's not the topic of your question and so neither will I make it that of this answer.

The way it does that is by combining your code with boilerplate of its own and compiling everything together.

> How can I write an application in Go and read Go files and execute it?

Either you write a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) or you do like Revel and just make an application which will compile other Go applications through the use of the Go compiler suite.

---

Edit to answer question in the comments: [Revel itself](https://github.com/revel/revel/blob/d021d0c3787ae6e81c713ce041b1b93075b04aa7/harness/build.go#L52) is a pretty good example. here on [line 73](https://github.com/revel/revel/blob/d021d0c3787ae6e81c713ce041b1b93075b04aa7/harness/build.go#L73) it executes `go build` with some flags and sets the output to `binName` which is a path to a temporary file.

Comment: Do you have a sample for `an application which will compile other Go applications through the use of the Go compiler suite.` I mean code sample.

Answer (score 3):

No, revel is not a virtual machine. Revel recompile your source code when you modify it.

That is described in features on http://revel.github.io/

> Hot Code Reload
>   Edit, save, and refresh. Revel compiles your code and templates for you, so you don't miss a beat. Code doesn't compile? It gives you a helpful description. Run-time code panic? Revel has you covered.

Go sources compiles very fast, so it becomes possible

Answer (score 0):

Revel is not a virtual machine. Infact it's a framework in Go.

As the home page of Revel says:

```
Hot Code Reload

Edit, save, and refresh. Revel compiles your code and templates for you, so you don't miss a beat. Code doesn't compile? It gives you a helpful description. Run-time code panic? Revel has you covered.
```